# Toggle visibilty of an element

Tags: javascript, css

so I am trying to create a button which would toggle between hidden and visible state. The thing is, I hate to first hide the element with javascript, as it is shown already visible, and then create a function to toggle between the states.

I have this code

```
jQuery('.prescriptions.eyeris-prescription.quote-item-options').css('visibility', 'collapse');
jQuery('<img />').attr({
      src:'https://cdn.eyerim.com/skin/frontend/eyerim/default/images/icons/ico_arrow_down.svg',
      content: '',
      display: 'block',
      width: '15px',
     height: '15px',
     class: 'dropdown-button',
}).appendTo(jQuery('#shopping-cart-form'));


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#dropdown-button').click(function(){
    jQuery('.prescriptions.eyeris-prescription.quote-item-options').toggle();
  });
});
```

in the first line I defined hiding the element, this works.

then I created a button and appended it to the element this also works.

but now I cant get the function right to toggle between the states.

could you please help me?

Comment: You have hidden your element using the `visibility` property, but jQuery’s `toggle` manipulates the `display` property to show or hide an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's true that you can use:

- `myElement.classList.toggle('is-visible')`

to toggle a given class, in **2019**, it is arguably better practice  to indicate ***element state*** by deploying HTML5 `data-*` custom attributes.

**eg.**

- `data-is-visible="true"`
- `data-is-visible="false"`

**Working Example:**

```js
const myButton = document.getElementsByClassName('my-button')[0];
const myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('my-div')[0];

const toggleDiv = () => {
  myDiv.dataset.isVisible = (myDiv.dataset.isVisible === 'false') ? 'true' : 'false';
}

myButton.addEventListener('click', toggleDiv, false);
```

```css
.my-button,
.my-div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.my-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 24px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.my-div[data-is-visible="false"] {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.my-div[data-is-visible="true"] {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="my-button">Toggle Visibility</button>
<div class="my-div" data-is-visible="false"></div>
```

Comment: this method is really great, it works even better than what I build together with other things, I will keep using this in the future thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:

```
jQuery('.prescriptions.eyeris-prescription.quote-item-options').css('visibility', 'collapse');
```

Hide element using css :

```
.prescriptions.eyeris-prescription.quote-item-options {
   display: none;
}
```

Then use Jquery to toggle element:

```
jQuery('#dropdown-button').click(function(){
    jQuery('.prescriptions.eyeris-prescription.quote-item-options').toggle();
});
```

Comment: hi. yes this would be great but the problem is I dont have access to CSS,  I have to overwrite CSS with Javascript. this should be an AB test

Comment: Then add this line:

Comment: jQuery('.prescriptions.eyeris-prescription.quote-item-options').hide();

Comment: hi, it worked with combination of different things but your answer helped too, thanks!